# INSERT output of a subquery along with an autoincrement in postgres

Tags: postgresql, insert, subquery

I am trying to store the output of a WITH statement in an INSERT statement in postgres along with an autoincrement id.

Below is the query:

```
INSERT
       INTO
            table
            (row_id,( 
             SELECT
                        *
                   FROM
                        final_dataset
            ));
```

However, I am getting a syntax error near "SELECT". I am unabe to figure out the solution to this.

Comment: What is `row_id` here? from where the values are coming for `row_id`. Please post some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
insert into the_table (col1, col2, col3)
select nextval('the_table_id_seq'), x1, x2 
from final_dataset;
```

If `col1` is a `serial` or `identity`column, I would remove it completely:

```
insert into the_table (col2, col3)
select x1, x2 
from final_dataset;
```

Comment: row_id is a column with serial numbers and I am adding all the columns from final_dataset to it and storing them into table.

Comment: @rshar: then use `select row_id, * from ...`